# What MS SQL Server administrator client should I use?

Tags: sql-server

I don't own a copy of MS SQL Server, but I've been given access to an instance on a remote machine. I need to log in, explore the database, and do some queries.

What admin client should I use? I'd rather not pay for anything. I downloaded MS SQL Server Management Studio Express, but it gives me a "can't connect to this version of SQL Server" error.

Edit:

Here's the actual error message:

This version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express can only be used to connect to SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005 servers.

Comment: What version of SQL Server is the remote machine running? What version of SSMS did you download? SSMS is the right tool, but you apparently have a version conflict.

Comment: I do not know what version the remote box is running. The ssms version is the most recent. I downloaded it today. I will paste the actual error message above.

Comment: Update: the remote box is 2008r2

Comment: Get the correct version of SQL Server that you are connecting to from the administrator that gave you the access to the remote instance like @ChrisS was suggesting.

Answer (score 4):

There are numerous versions of SSMS available for download, you have one that's 8 YEARS old.

You should download an install the 2012 SQL Server Management Studio Express. You can find it on [Microsoft's SQL 2012 Downloaeds Page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062), it's the last link in that pile of downloads.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more.

Comment: I guess when the OP commented: "The ssms version is the most recent. I downloaded it today.", he must have meant he downloaded the most recent version of SSMS 2005.